# Is there any way to comment out text in textile?

Tags: markup, textile, comments

LaTeX has `%`, html has `<\!--` to denote that a comment folows.

Does textile have anyway of commenting out text? I couldn't find one, and it seems like it would be a nice feature to have.

Answer (score 5):

Not really. It seems you can do a single line HTML escape sequence containing an HTML comment which is passed through.   But you probably want something more like the C Preprocessor comments that are simply stripped out completely?

```
==<!-- html comment -->==
```

Or you could do this, which outputs a multiline html comment, but I doubt it's what you want either:

```
notextile.  <!-- test 
test
test
-->
```

Comment: For me in the future, the solution <notextile><!-- comment goes here --></notextile> worked for multi-paragraph comments.

Answer (score 1):

The TextPattern version of Textile [does support comments](http://txstyle.org/doc/40/textile-comments).

The syntax is to have a line beginning with three hashes and one or two full stops.

```
###. This line will be treated as a comment.
So will this.

This line will be displayed.

###.. Blank lines are allowed in comments if you use two full stops.

This line is also a comment.

p. Starting a new block will end the comment.
```

Currently, the [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/) and [Mylyn](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Incubator/WikiText) implementations of Textile do not support these comments.